# python inactive system, detect keyboard activity

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple python program that will detect if either my keyboard or mouse are idle, and if so to move the mouse.. this is to circumvent an idle logout timeout on a macbook.. I can't change these settings as they're policies pushed by my employer. It's set to like 3 minutes which is extremely annoying. I have it working for mouse inactivity, but not keyboard

How would I, or what library would i use to detect if no keyboard activity has happened?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyautogui
import time
from random import randrange


def timer():
    get_time = int(time.time())
    return get_time 


def main():

    while True:
        snapshot = { "time" : timer(), "position" : pyautogui.position() }
        time.sleep(5)
        if snapshot["position"] == pyautogui.position():
            pyautogui.moveTo(400,randrange(1,50))
        else:
            pass

main()
```

Comment: You could consider just moving the cursor by a single pixel every 3 minutes. You probably wouldn't notice this while working.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar here https://gitlab.com/shakerloops/shakerloops

But I don't think I was detecting key events.

Even so, you could theoretically just use keyevent from pygame or wxpython. both can detect keyboard events without actually launching a GUI. Example:

https://gitlab.com/makerbox/alluvial/raw/master/usr/local/bin/alluvial/alluvial.py

Those two combined ought to work!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant to your case and I know it doesn't work totally for mac as I did it on Windows but I'll give you an idea how I managed it.

The reason is that although the keyboard package works for mac, the mouse package is available only for windows and Unix.

You mentioned that detecting mouse inactivity is working and I was facing the same issue (able to detect mouse inactivity but not keyboard inactivity) so I tied keyboard activity with mouse activity.
Practically this means that whenever I use the keyboard, the mouse moves around like a few pixels in different directions. This will create mouse activity that will signal the program that the keyboard is active as well (I chose a few keys that I regularly use to make the mouse move around).

```
import mouse
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey("space", lambda: mouse.move(4, 5, absolute=False, duration=0.01))
keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl", lambda: mouse.move(-2, -8, absolute=False, duration=0.01))
keyboard.add_hotkey("shift", lambda: mouse.move(3, -4, absolute=False, duration=0.01))
keyboard.add_hotkey("alt", lambda: mouse.move(-7, 2, absolute=False, duration=0.01))
keyboard.add_hotkey("e", lambda: mouse.move(-3, -6, absolute=False, duration=0.01))
```

Comment: If anyone is interested in knowing how to detect mouse inactivity using the mouse package, it's simply done by assigning a variable to the mouse coordinates locmouse1 = mouse.get_position() and then comparing them to the coordinates (set in another variable: locmouse2 = mouse.get_position()) after a certain time (time.sleep(5)).

Answer (score 0):

Recently was trying to do something similar that involved doing an action after idling for a certain amount of time. Here's what I used. It detects both keyboard and mouse actions in any window:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time
import pyautogui

idle_action = 60 ##number of seconds for idle

idled_time = [time.time()] ##use a list so no global/local variable conflict happens
idle_pos = [pyautogui.position()]

def update_idle(key):
    idled_time.append(time.time())
    idle_pos.append(pyautogui.position())

with Listener(on_press=update_idle) as listener:
    while True:
        for i in range(len(idle_pos)-1): ##only the latest value in each list is the actual value
            del idle_pos[0]
        for i in range(len(idled_time)-1):
            del idled_time[0]
        current_pos = pyautogui.position()
        if current_pos!=idle_pos[0]:
            update_idle(None)
        elif time.time()-idled_time[0]>idle_action:
            do_what_you_want_to_do() #<----
```